# fuelphp routes to angular routes

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, fuelphp

I have routes and request handling mechanism written in fuelphp to calculate the template in server side.

Computing templates on server side is slower in my understanding and I would like to covert all routes to angular routing.

Most of the fuelphp code outputs angularjs views.

Is there a direct or quicker way to convert all php routes to angular routes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
In your public folder make a .htaccess file and fill it with the following

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```